# Plotting Multiple Lines on Graph for Different groups in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to edit a plot that I created in ggplot such that each facet shows 2 different lines overlapping (one for avg. actual run hours, one for avg. scheduled run hours) as well as display a legend to the right to indicate which line is actual vs. scheduled.  I referenced the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635799/ggplot-2-facets-with-multiple-lines) but was unable to get the solution to work in my case because I'm dealing with different columns that need to be overlapped, and not a group within one variable.  Please note that the lines will be nearly identical in this case, but I have other use cases involving the same task where the lines will differ significantly - hence the request for help.

My data is listed below for reference:

```
structure(list(month_yr = c("2022-01", "2022-01", "2022-02", 
"2022-02", "2022-03", "2022-03", "2022-04", "2022-04", "2022-05", 
"2022-05", "2022-06", "2022-06", "2022-07", "2022-07", "2022-08", 
"2022-08", "2022-09", "2022-09", "2022-10", "2022-10", "2022-11", 
"2022-11", "2022-12", "2022-12", "2023-01", "2023-01", "2023-02", 
"2023-02"), plant_name = c("plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s", 
"plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s", 
"plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s", 
"plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s", 
"plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s", "plant_f", "plant_s"
), avg_run_hours = c(15.0080608695652, 16.3453608247423, 14.7394112149533, 
16.1025555555556, 14.9570175438596, 15.7327777777778, 17.0074257425743, 
16.5604901960784, 16.989010989011, 16.3021296296296, 14.8100961538462, 
15.8714516129032, 16.5552083333333, 15.3971568627451, 16.2258771929825, 
14.2616279069767, 17.2556179775281, 14.3790350877193, 16.3594903846154, 
15.5988617886179, 14.4050925925926, 15.9334920634921, 14.3455056179775, 
16.6322935779817, 16.6958762886598, 17.1025714285714, 16.046875, 
16.8408695652174), avg_sched_run_hours = c(15.0267043478261, 
16.4351340206186, 15.0025140186916, 16.2041555555556, 14.8281578947368, 
15.9119814814815, 17.1840099009901, 16.7646666666667, 17.0109340659341, 
16.4446388888889, 14.7679615384615, 16.1768790322581, 16.3242083333333, 
15.7033333333333, 16.343701754386, 14.5158139534884, 17.4342921348315, 
14.5827280701754, 16.4562692307692, 15.4149105691057, 14.2729537037037, 
16.1438253968254, 14.3073595505618, 16.7186330275229, 16.6436082474227, 
17.0332952380952, 16.3137916666667, 16.9656739130435)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), groups = structure(list(
    month_yr = c("2022-01", "2022-02", "2022-03", "2022-04", 
    "2022-05", "2022-06", "2022-07", "2022-08", "2022-09", "2022-10", 
    "2022-11", "2022-12", "2023-01", "2023-02"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 
        19:20, 21:22, 23:24, 25:26, 27:28), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -14L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Code I used to create the image below:

```
hours_by_plant <-
    ggplot(so_run_hour_stats, aes(x=month_yr, y=avg_sched_run_hours, group=1)) + geom_point() +
    geom_line(color="red") + xlab("Month of Year") + ylab("Avg Run Hours") +
    ggtitle("Avg Plant Run Hours by Month from 01/2022 - 02/2023") + theme_classic() +
    facet_wrap(~plant_name)

hours_by_plant <- hours_by_plant + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: Plot that needs slight editing (another line added to each facet)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

I also transform the dates into real date objects and edit the `avg_*` columns after pivoting.

You can set the x axis date breaks to different values if you want to, for instance, to 1 month.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

so_run_hour_stats %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("avg"), names_to = "Average") %>%
  mutate(month_yr = as.Date(paste0(month_yr, "-01")),
         Average = sub("avg_", "", Average),
         Average = gsub("_", " ", Average)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(month_yr, value, colour = Average)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(color = "black") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%Y-%m") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  facet_wrap(~ plant_name) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>